# See where variable value is set when debugging in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I would like to know if when debugging in Eclipse, is there a feature/way to focus on a variable and "back-track" where the variable got its value..? I hope I'm being clear enough, but I can see if this appears as a weird question.

The thing is, I have two similar classes, both using a @Resource instance of the same class. One of the classes runs fine but the other one gets a NullPointerException for the instance variable in question. And I can't see how this is. So if you know a way to "back-track" in the Eclipse debugger to see "how old" and where a value in a variable is set I would greatly appreciate it!

And if there's no such feature for some obvious reason and this question in stupid I apologize in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to set a field breakpoint on the field in question *before* the value is set and catch it when it happens. "Standard" debuggers don't have the back-in-time feature. Omniscient debuggers do, though. These record every single action taken by a VM so that you can ask these kinds of questions at any point during execution. They're not widely used and have understandably high performance penalties. There are at least a couple of open source ones out there: [TOD](http://pleiad.dcc.uchile.cl/tod/) and [ODB](http://www.lambdacs.com/debugger/).

Comment: I didn't know about these open-source alternatives but they look interesting. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that might be just what I need! I suppose the strains on performance could be an issue, and is probably the reason why Eclipse doesn't have it..

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not possible in the standard Eclipse debugger. There is a commercial product called ["Chronon Time-Travelling Debugger"](http://www.chrononsystems.com/), which I have not tried but [sounds as if it might do what you want](http://java.dzone.com/articles/introducing-chronon-time), and is available for a 30-day free trial.